# SQL Server : select statement where value have format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find special string that has a format like `##-%`, start from two character and '-'

```
select * 
from temp 
where name like '##-%'
```

Give me some advice, or example how I can get this?

And how can I replace this format on empty string ""

Comment: select * from temp where name like '__-%'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If would you find the special character which is start from two character and '-'

```
select * from temp where name like '[a-z][a-z]-%'
```

if would you want to find the special string have format like '##-%

```
select * from temp where name like '##-[%]%'
```

If would you want to find the third letter is '-'

```
select * from temp where name like '__-%'
```

Answer (score 4):

Add underscores for how many characters you need at start.In your case its two `__`

```
select * from temp where name like '__-%'
```

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple. Just use [ ] around '%' to escape it.

> > Select * From temp 
> >     Where name like '##-[%]%'

Answer (score 2):

This will return any record where the 3rd character in the 'name' column is '-'

```
SELECT * 
FROM temp 
WHERE SUBSTRING(name, 3, 1) = '-'
```